# Where can I find a complete list of Bitcoin forks (soft, hard, intentional and unintentional)

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain-fork, consensus, bip, soft-fork

I was looking to study the history of Bitcoin forks including the 2013 incident that may or may not have been a Hard fork depending on your definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a paper that provides extensive detail on the history of all kind of forks on Bitocin, Ethereum and Ethereum Classic, you can read it here, ***[Atomically Trading with Roger: Gambling on the success of a hardfork](https://web.archive.org/web/20171116062404/http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/patrick.mc-corry/atomically-trading-roger.pdf)***.

Here is the list of Forks so far,

[image]

The following content is sourced from the above paper,

> So far, Bitcoin has implemented over six softforks. These softforks
> range from introducing rules to prevent miners creating coinbase
> transactions with duplicated identification hashes, requiring all
> ECDSA signatures to strictly enforce DER coding, and introducing both
> absolute and relative lock times for individual transaction outputs.
> In terms of implementation, this involves storing new information in
> the scriptsig of the coinbase transaction, constraining transaction
> validation rules or re-defining the use of special OP_NOP function.
>    On
> the other hand, Bitcoin has experienced two accidental (and temporary)
> splits (i.e. Fork-1, Fork-2 emerged) that required miner intervention
> to remedy. The first split permitted a user to exploit an integer
> overflow bug and create 184 billion coins. This required miners to
> co-operatively extend a new blockchain without the coin creation
> transaction [6] and to enforce a soft-fork to prevent this exploit.
> The second split involved miners who upgraded to Bitcoin Core 0.8
> accidentally creating blocks that were invalid for Bitcoin Core 0.7.
> Unfortunately, BerkeleyDB’s configuration in Bitcoin Core 0.7 was
> non-deterministic and as a result was not compatible with LevelDB’s
> configuration in Bitcoin Core 0.8. Resolving this fork required miners
> to immediately downgrade to Bitcoin Core 0.7 and abandon the forked
> blockchain. Next, the developers released Bitcoin Core 8.1 that
> enforced the activation of a hardfork12 after a two-month grace period
> for miners and users to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

The best resource I've seen that answers this question is this BitMEX [blog post](https://blog.bitmex.com/bitcoins-consensus-forks/). It includes some of the early Satoshi era forks that haven't been included in any existing answers.

[image: BitMEX table]

Answer (score -3):

On their github:

Please reffer to githubs help page for [searching issues](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/).

**Examples**:
This is just example of how you could use it in searching for "issue" from 2013-01-01 to 2013-12-31:
`search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=issue+created%3A%222013-01-01+..+2013-12-31%22&type=Issues`

Full link for bitcoin's issues from that period core would be: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=issue+created%3A%222013-01-01+..+2013-12-31%22&type=Issues

This would look for "bug" for the same periods:
`search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bug+created%3A%222013-01-01+..+2013-12-31%22&type=Issues`

I do not have enough reputation to post you more than 2 link: `h++ps://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bug%20created%3A%222013-01-01%20..%202013-12-31%22&type=Issues`

*You could apply the same on cards and projects*