# Which major/noteworthy BIPs, Soft-Forks and Hard Forks have there been since the Summer of 2017 (after SegWit/Bitcoin Cash)?

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-core-development, consensus

There are many lists of major forks however most of them end after SegWit. The full list of BIPs is extensive. Which noteworthy BIPs, Soft Forks and Hard Forks have there been since SegWit and Bitcoin Cash (i.e. After Summer of 2017)?

- [Bitmex List](https://blog.bitmex.com/bitcoins-consensus-forks/)
- [Book List](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5708/commits/b63ae5626910eaa41337c8173cac0c4728a5432d)
- [Full List of BIPS](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56607/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-bitcoin-forks-soft-hard-intentional-and-u)

Comment: "have there been" -> could you clarify whether you mean BIPs that have been activated, proposed, or iterated upon?

Comment: Also, are you specifically referring to consensus changing BIPs (ones that involve a softfork), or any type of BIP? Most are about interactions between wallets and network protocols; the ones proposing consensus changes to Bitcoin are a minority.